# not getting new updated data while using AJAX in calling partial file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file, html, partial

I have called the partial file form the loop. now when i update , i do not actually get updated result but need to do refresh for getting updated result.
the code is like this :

**the file1**

```
  @folders.each do |@folder|
  = render :partial => 'folders/group_list'
```

**the partial file**

```
%div{:id => "group_list_#{@folder.id}"}  // this is the div which needs to be updated
  = group_member(@folder)   //this is the helper method
```

I need the updated @folder from controller but I always get file1's @folder

**controller side**

```
def any_method
  ..
  some code
  ..
  @folder = Folder.find(params[:folder_id])
  render :partial => '/folders/group_list'
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code that makes the Ajax call, and a sample of the logs showing what is happening during that call?

Comment: And if you're using RJS, post that code too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had much experience with Rails? If I'm interpreting your post correctly, you seem to be going about things in the wrong way.

It looks like you're using haml to me. If so, your files should look more like this:

**file1:**

```
= render :partial => 'folders/group_list', :collection => @folders
```

This renders the partial folders/group_list once for each item in @folders.

**partial file:**

```
%div{ :id => "group_list_#{group_list.id}"
    = group_member(folder)
```

By default, the variable accessible in the partial is named after the partial itself. So you get the id of group_list, not folder. You can modify this behavior by passing the :as argument to render().

**controller:**

```
def ajax_method
    @folder = Folder.find(params[:folder_id])
    render :update do |page|
        page.replace "group_list_#{@folder.id}", :partial => 'folders/group_list', :object => @folder
    end
end
```